# Cauchy Equation and Continuity

Tags: continuity, compactness, unbounded-operators, cauchy-riemann-equations

Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued function defined on all of $R$ and satisfying the identity
$$ f(x+y)=f(x) f(y)$$
for all $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that, if $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $f$ is continuous on all of $R$.

Initially, one has to prove that $f(0)=1$ since otherwise $f$ would be identically equal to $0$, as well as $f(x) \geq 0$ is true for all $x \in R$. Moreover, the main approach seems to use the epsilon-delta technique, however, I couldn’t be able to prove mathematically how this relation can be correct using the above identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.
Then for every $y\in\Bbb R$ it holds that
$$f(x+y)-f(x)=f(x)f(y)-f(x)=f(x)(f(y)-1)=f(x)(f(y)-f(0))$$

Assume $f$ is contoinuous at $0$, so $\lim_{y\to0}f(y)=f(0)$. Then
$$\lim_{y\to0}(f(x+y)-f(x))=\lim_{y\to0}f(x)(f(y)-f(0))=0$$ and this menas that $$\lim_{y\to0}f(x+y)=f(x)$$

So $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: More clarification about the details would be really appreciated, want to know detailedly that we are on the right track.

Comment: The second equality is backwards.  It should be $f(x)f(y)-f(x)=f(x)(f(y)-1)$.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected

Comment: @TitoEliatron I think you only proved continuity at zero. It is necessary to prove that $\lim_{c\to0}f(y)=f(c)$ for any real number $c$, whereas your statements are only covering the case for when values approach zero.

Comment: No, @Snowflake I prove that If $f(y)\to f(0)=1$ as $y\to 0$ (that is, if $f$ is continuous at $0$), then $f(x+y)\to f(x)$ as $y\to 0$ (that is, $f$ is continupous at $x$)